# Fastest way of copy files from Ext3 to NTFS?

Tags: linux, ntfs, file-transfer, ext3

I’m right now on a Ubuntu Live CD and need to copy 500GB of several big files (videos) from an Ext3 file system to a NTFS file system (it’s an emergency backup since the Ext3 is doing weird noises).

What’s the fastest way to do this, unattended, I mean, skipping errors, etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Newer Ubuntu distributions have the ntfs-3g driver already installed, so we can probably mount the drive:

```
mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

if it's a SCSI or SATA type disk it will be sd*. sda for the first drive, sdb for the second, and so on. If it's an IDE drive it will be hd*. hda for the first, hdb for the second, and so on.

now copy the folder recursively:

```
cp -R /path/to/videos /mnt
```

Comment: It's worth noting that Linux treats SATA drives like SCSI ones, so SATA disks also show up as /dev/sdX

Comment: Adding _-o big_writes_ to the ntfs-3g mount operation (I recommend using the _ntfs-3g_ command instead of _mount_) will speed up significantly the writing!

Answer (score -1):

Fastest way I know:

```
mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /mnt
cd /your/videos
tar - . | (cd /mnt; tar xf - )
```

Reduction in transfer size = faster transfer.

Comment: I doubt that the pipe is the bottleneck here.  And errors will still likely block the transfer.