# Mount a NTFS Partition in Xubuntu

Tags: partitioning, xubuntu

I was wondering what the best way to mount a NTFS partition in Ubuntu would be. I created an NTFS drive where I store things that I want both a Windows and Xubuntu to have read/write access to. Also, is there a better way to do this in your opinions?

EDIT: Found an answer to the first question in:

[Fastest way of copy files from Ext3 to NTFS?](https://superuser.com/questions/94457/fastest-way-of-copy-files-from-ext3-to-ntfs)

But still wondering if this (by this I mean the setup where I use the NTFS partition as a shared partition) is the best way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Guess this is a duplicate. Just search for "ntfs linux" and such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using an NTFS partition is the best way. NTFS support used to be problematic under Linux, but with the NTFS-3G driver, it is very solid. As Windows has very little support for other filesystems, using NTFS is the way to go.

Another option would be a VFAT partition, but as VFAT has numerous problems (checkdisk after unclean shutdown, no files >4GB, inefficient for large partitions), NTFS is preferred.